# IO:Error Ipython notebook

Tags: python, hdf5, ioerror, h5py

I have a problem with creating a hdf5 file. On ubuntu it run without error messages. But when I try the code on windows 8 I get an IO:Error. I do not know how to get arround this problem.
My code for the cell (The rest of the code is to big to post it right here) is:

```
w = Wavefront(wfr)
w.store_hdf5('tmp/fin1.h5') 
w=Wavefront()
w.load_hdf5('tmp/fin1.h5')
```

By running this cell the following error message appears:

```
 IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-10-b13a63fc6b64> in <module>()
  1 w = Wavefront(wfr)
----> 2 w.store_hdf5('tmp/fin1.h5')
  3 w=Wavefront()
  4 w.load_hdf5('tmp/fin1.h5')
  5 

C:\Users\grumpy\Desktop\wavefront-feature-srw_update_Sept2013\samples\srw_python\wpg\wavefront.pyc in store_hdf5(self, file_name)
103 
104     def store_hdf5(self, file_name):
--> 105         utils.store_dict_hdf5(file_name, self.to_dict())
106         self.store_attributes(file_name)
107 

C:\Users\grumpy\Desktop\wavefront-feature-srw_update_Sept2013\samples   \srw_python\wpg\utils.pyc in store_dict_hdf5(hdf5_file_name, input_dict)
 46 
 47 
  ---> 48     with h5py.File(hdf5_file_name, 'w') as res_file:
 49         store_group(input_dict, res_file)
 50 

C:\Users\grumpy\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.pyc in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, **kwds)
229             driver, HDF5 still requires this be non-empty.
230         driver
--> 231             Name of the driver to use.  Legal values are None (default,
232             recommended), 'core', 'sec2', 'stdio', 'mpio'.
233         libver

C:\Users\grumpy\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.pyc in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl)
 82             fcpl = h5p.create(h5p.FILE_CREATE)
 83         fcpl.set_userblock(userblock_size)
---> 84 
 85     if mode == 'r':
 86         flags = h5f.ACC_RDONLY

 h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-2.4.x\h5py\_objects.c:2413)()

 h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (D:\Buil \h5py\h5py-2.4.x\h5py\_objects.c:2370)()

 h5py\h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.create (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-2.4.x\h5py\h5f.c:1919)()

 IOError: Unable to create file (Unable to open file: name = 'tmp/fin1.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'no such file or directory', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)
```

Comment: Is there a `tmp` folder in the directory where you're running that? If not, you need to create it before you run that code.

Comment: yes there are  a tmp folder.

Comment: but as i removed the folder tmp/fin1.h5 and saved it again in that directory, the code worked.